# How to do custom query in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to write a custom query in magento website.

I created a file test.php in my magento root folder & written a custom query

```
<?php
 $read= Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
 $value=$read->query("Select * from catalog_product_flat_1");
 $row = $value->fetch();
 echo "<pre>";print_r($row);echo "</pre>";
?>
```

But it is not giving me any results.Please guide me.

Comment: you should not write any custom query in Magento, use the models instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "Select * from catalog_product_flat_1";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),...
Zend_Debug::dump($rows);
```

In order to test, you can create sandbox.php file in root of your magento installation and paste the following code:

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "Select * from catalog_product_flat_1";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),...
Zend_Debug::dump($rows);
```

and call from url as:

```
http://your-magento-url/sandbox.php
```

Comment: It should work. Try to wrap your code within try{} catch{} block and turn on the developer mode.

Comment: Thank you very much MagePsycho !!

Comment: For scripts you might want to have a look into the `/shell` folder. See http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/php-shell-scripts-for-magento/