# Custom MySQL Query in Magento is returning wrong values

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've added an extra table to the Magento DB, called kv_mailings. Some extra productinfo is stored in there which doesn't have anything to do with Magento. That's why I've added an extra table.

I used the test.php idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11792865/1327289) and my file looks like this:

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM kv_mailings WHERE sku=hkag";
$row = $connection->fetchRow($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),...

Zend_Debug::dump($row);
```

My table currently looks like this:

[image: current table]

This is where the crazy stuff starts. When my query is `SELECT * FROM kv_mailings WHERE sku=SKU` It will select the correct row and return:

```
array(9) {
  ["id"] => string(1) "1"
  ["titel"] => string(19) "value"
  ["sku"] => string(3) "SKU"
  ["logo"] => string(96) "value"
  ["background"] => string(84) "value"
  ["codes_new"] => string(0) ""
  ["codes_old"] => string(419) "value"
  ["codes_enc"] => string(6) "CODE11"
  ["terms"] => string(708) "value"
}
```

*note that I've changed the actual values to `value`.

If I change the query to `SELECT * FROM kv_mailings WHERE sku=hkag` I'll get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'hkag' in 'where clause'' in /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT * FROM k...', Array) #5 /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT * FROM k...', Array) #6 /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Zend/Db/Adapt in /var/www/webshop.test.vtnl.net/https/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234
```

What's up with that? As you can see there IS a record in the table where sku = hkag... Does anyone know what is happening and what I can do about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Select Statement `hkag` is a string, so it should be in quote

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM kv_mailings WHERE sku='hkag'";
```

For security it would be better to do (see [MySQL prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement))

```
$coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $coreResource->getConnection('core_read');

$select = $connection->select()
    ->from( $coreResource->getTableName('{moduleName}/kv_mailings'))), //->from('kv_mailings')
    ->where('sku = ?', 'hkag');

$row = $connection->fetchOne($select);
```

Or

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM kv_mailings WHERE sku=?";
  $row = $connection->fetchRow($sql, 'hkag' );
```

Take a look @ http://www.vortexcommerce.com/blog/magento-direct-sql

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver! I've been watching at Magento code for too long and didn't even think about adding quotes. :/

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is content string so you must have to write in string to check in your magento database

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM kv_mailings WHERE sku='hkag'";
```

you can try with below code

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM kv_mailings WHERE sku='hkag'";
$row = $connection->fetchRow($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),...

Zend_Debug::dump($row);
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "select * from test"
$row = $connection->fetchRow($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),...

you can check which method is available in this $connection  object by simple way:

echo "<pre>" ;
print_r(get_class_methods($connections));


please check below url for more reference
```

[Custom sql Query in magento](http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/how-to-select-insert-update-and-delete-data-in-magento-database/) 
   [Magento: How to select, insert, update, and delete data?](http://jyotiloppy.blogspot.in/2013/10/magento-how-to-select-insert-update-and.html)