# Run mysql complex query in magento 1.8.0.0 version

Tags: mysql, magento

How to run below mysql query in magento 1.8.0.0

```
select
    m.*,
    group_concat(c.store_id)
from
    news m
    join news_store c on find_in_set(c.news_id, m.news_id)
group by
    m.news_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows :

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

// now $write is an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
$read ->query("select m.*,
    group_concat(c.store_id)
    from
    news m
    join news_store c on find_in_set(c.news_id, m.news_id)
    group by
    m.news_id");
```

[How to do custom query in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792762/how-to-do-custom-query-in-magento)